# How do I change the value of one cookie in 'Cookie' (in the header field) with XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cookies, cordova, xmlhttprequest

i am developing an app using phonegap for mobile platforms. For that im using js and so need to do many ajax calls. What i need to do is add a cookie (or modify its value if its already present) in the request header of an XMLHttpRequest. 
I know it says here that its not possible - [How do I SET a Cookie (header) with XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320110/how-do-i-set-a-cookie-header-with-xmlhttprequest-in-javascript)
But one seems to be able to modify the value of the 'Cookie' field in request headers, before making the xhr call, as its given in the answer here: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/120728/set-cookies-using-setrequestheader--crashed-   
 
It says that we can set the 'Cookie' field of the xhr req header for android and iphone in different ways like this:

```
if (Titanium.Platform.name == 'iPhone OS')  
{
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cookie", "cookie1=value1");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cookie", "cookie2=value2");
}
else
{
var cookieString = "cookie1=value1; cookie2=value2;";
xhr.setRequestHeader('Cookie', cookieString);
}
```

but im just using js, i cant use methods/classes for iphone/android. 
what i need to know is, if the browser sends a 'Cookie' header something like

`xyz_cookie=vd0dKmD4mT; qwe=13aef60f7d0845` 
can i add another cookie `"abc=1317331740;"` by using the `xhr.setRequestHeader` method in a way that the browser sends all 3 cookies

`xyz_cookie=vd0dKmD4mT; qwe=13aef60f7d0845 abc=1317331740;`

 in the cookie field in the request header of xhr? 
If yes, pls tell me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xhr.setRequestHeader cant be used to set Cookie according to w3c recommendations.
i guess thats why it was failing.  :-(
Also that cookies dont work on phonegap android apps. so that was adding to the document.cookie confusion.