# Cookie is not set in browser

Tags: angularjs, jakarta-ee, cookies

I have been trying to connect the JAX-RS web service with AngularJS frontend. As you can see at the attached screenshots, the Chrome can read and parse the Set-Cookie value, but dismisses it for unknown reason.

JAX-RS snippet:

```
c1 = new NewCookie("session_id", uuid, "/", null, null, COOKIE_MAX_AGE, false);

return Response.status(200).cookie(c1).build();
```

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, it was caused by the bad request. I did't set the " withCredentials: true" field in my AngularJS $http.post request.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8530284/1349442